# How do I disable a submit button by default until it's text area has 1 character or more typed into it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, submit-button

Currently when text area is focused on it expands it's height and the post and cancel button appear. Now I'd like to disable the submit button by default and only make it active once the text area has been typed into.

Later on I'll add opacity to the inactive submit button then take it away when the button is active just for a nice effect. But anyway I've tried applying disabled many ways and it doesn't work. I've tried various other things such as define a click function as well as submit then apply disabled using attr() to the disabled attribute of my form and it seems to have no effect.

**HTML**

```
        <div class="comment_container">
                    <%= link_to image_tag(default_photo_for_commenter(comment), :class => "commenter_photo"), commenter(comment.user_id).username %>

                    <div class="commenter_content"> <div class="userNameFontStyle"><%= link_to commenter(comment.user_id).username.capitalize, commenter(comment.user_id).username %> - <%=  simple_format h(comment.content) %> </div>
                </div><div class="comment_post_time"> <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago. </div>


           </div>


                    <% end %>
                <% end %>


            <% if logged_in? %>
            <%= form_for @comment, :remote => true do |f| %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :micropost_id, :value => m.id %>
            <%= f.text_area :content, :placeholder => 'Post a comment...', :class => "comment_box", :rows => 0, :columns => 0 %>

    <div class="commentButtons">         
      <%= f.submit 'Post it', :class => "commentButton" %>
   <div class="cancelButton"> Cancel </div>
    </div>   
            <% end %>

            <% end %>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(".microposts").on("focus", ".comment_box", function() {
    this.rows = 7;


    var $commentBox = $(this),
        $form = $(this).parent(),
        $cancelButton = $form.children(".commentButtons").children(".cancelButton");
       // $commentButton = $form.children(".commentButtons").children(".commentButton");
            $(this).removeClass("comment_box").addClass("comment_box_focused").autoResize();  
            $form.children(".commentButtons").addClass("displayButtons");

                $cancelButton.click(function() {
                    $commentBox.removeClass("comment_box_focused").addClass("comment_box");
                    $form.children(".commentButtons").removeClass("displayButtons");
                    $commentBox.val("");



                });

});
```

kind regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the disabled attribute doesn't work because if the disabled attribute is present, the field is disabled, regardless of the value of the attribute. You could use `.removeAttr("disabled")`, but it really makes the most sense to manipulate the `disabled` *property* which is more intuitive - it's just a boolean.

```
$commentButton.prop({ disabled: !$commentBox.val());
```

To be safe, bind to `onkeyup`, `oninput`, and `onchange`:

```
$commentBox.on("keyup input change", function () {
    $commentButton.prop({ disabled: !$commentBox.val() });
});
```

If you need to manually enable or disable the button, such as after clearing the form, you can pass `true` or `false` directly to a call to `.prop()`.

```
$commentButton.prop({ disabled: true });
```

---

**Edit:** Detailed breakdown

### The `.prop()` method

The [`.prop()` method](http://api.jquery.com/prop) gets and sets property values on elements, similar to how `.attr()` gets and sets attribute values on elements.

Considering this jQuery:

```
var myBtn = $("#myBtn");
myBtn.prop("disabled", true);
```

We can re-write that in plain JavaScript like this:

```
var myBtn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
myBtn.disabled = true;
```

### Why we don't need an `if` statement

The reason we don't need an `if` statement is that the `disabled` property takes a boolean value.  We *could* put a boolean expression in an `if` statement, and then depending on the result, assign a different boolean expression as the value of the property:

```
if (someValue == true) {
    myObj.someProperty = false;
}
else {
    myObj.someProperty = true;
}
```

The first problem is the redundancy in the `if` statement:  `if (someValue == true)` can be shortened to `if (someValue)`.  Second, the whole block can be shortened to a single statement by using the [logical not operator (`!`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zz722703%28VS.94%29.aspx):

```
myObj.someProperty = !someValue;
```

The logical not operator (`!`) returns the negated result of an expression - ie `true` for "falsey" values, and `false` for "truthy" values.  If you aren't familier with "truthy" and "falsey" values, here's a quick primer.  Any time you use a non-boolean value where a boolean is expected, the value is coerced to boolean.  Values that evaluate to `true` are said to be "truthy" and values that evaluate to `false` are said to be "falsey".

```
 Type     Falsey values      Truthy values
 ———————— —————————————————— ——————————————————————
 Number   0, NaN             Any other number
 String   ""                 Any non-empty string
 Object   null, undefined    Any non-null object
```

Since an empty string evaluates to false, we can get a boolean indicating whether there is any text in the textarea by applying `!` to the value:

```
var isEmpty = !$commentBox.val();
```

Or, use `!!` to do a double negation and effectively coerce a string value to boolean:

```
var hasValue = !!$commentBox.val();
```

We could rewrite the jQuery from above to a more verbose form in plain JavaScript:

```
var myBtn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var myTextBox = document.getElementById("myTextBox");
var text = myTextBox.value;
var isEmpty = !text;
if (isEmpty) {
    myBtn.disabled = true;
}
else {
    myBtn.disabled = false;
}
```

Or, a little shorter, and more similar to the original:

```
var myBtn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var myTextBox = document.getElementById("myTextBox");
myBtn.disabled = !myTextBox.value;
```

Comment: Gave this a try but for some reason when pasted into my existing code it stops the commentBox text area from expanding.

Comment: @London - whoops!  I'm answering from my phone. Fixed.

Comment: Trying to understand this code and why no if statement was needed. What does prop do? I'll take a look at the jquery documentation. Would you be able to comment this code as I'd like to understand it slightly more.

Comment: When I post a comment and then start the process again the button is active.

Comment: Tried this again and it worked. The reason it didn't work the first time was because I didn't manually set disabled to true so when the form was loaded again it let me submit. I preferred this answer because of it's thoroughness.

Comment: Also from reading through the JQuery .prop(), removeProp() docs I see that I should be using these instead of attr() as I'm using JQuery 1.7

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
var submit = $("input[type=submit]");
submit.attr("disabled","disabled");

$('textarea.comment_box').keyup(function() {
    if ( !$(this).val() ) {
       submit.attr("disabled","disabled");
    } else {
       submit.removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

Here's a JS Fiddle so that you can try this out: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/a2BND/

Answer (score 1):

You can first disable your submit button, and if textarea has a value enable it:

```
<form id="yourForm">
<textarea id="ta"></textarea>
<input id="submit" type="submit" disabled="disabled">    
<form> 

$("#yourForm").change(function() {

  if ( $("#ta").val().length >= 1) {

    $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled"); 
  }

  else {

    $("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");

  }              

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dY8Bg/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this task using keyup event on text area. sample concept code below.

```
$("#textareaid").on('keyup', function (e) {
     Count_Chars(this);
});

function Count_Chars(obj) {
    var len = obj.value.length;
    if (len >= 1) {
        // do task
        // enable post button
    }
}
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Added this to existing code to accomplish what I wanted. Marked answer that help me the most as winning answer and marked up others that helped.

```
commentButton = form.children(".commentButtons").children(".commentButton");

       commentButton.attr("disabled","disabled");

        commentBox.keyup(function() {
            if ( !$(this).val() ) {
               commentButton.attr("disabled","disabled");
            } else {
               commentButton.removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        });
```